# Existence of solution to Newton's equation on a manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection associated with $g$. Newton's equation is
$$
  \nabla_{\dot \gamma(t)} \dot{\gamma}(t) = - \text{grad} \; U(\gamma(t))
$$
where $U$ is some smooth function (the potential) on $M$. In the case that $U$ is constant, we recover the geodesic equation. In this case, we have existence theorem that states there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p \in M$ and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 > 0$ so that for $q \in U$ and $v 
\in T_qM$ with $\|v\| < \epsilon_1$ there is a unique geodesic
$$
  \gamma_v : (-2\epsilon_2,2\epsilon_2) \rightarrow M
$$
with initial condition $\gamma_v(0) =q$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v$. So the question is:

Is there a general result for nice potential function $U$?

Answer (score 0):

I think the addition of the smooth potential function makes no difference.  Look at what I wrote here:

[Is a geodesic always regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581099/is-a-geodesic-always-regular/581295#581295)